# List index out of range error in matrix

Tags: python, list, matrix

I'm trying to apply different textures to a block depending on what blocks are around it, but I'm getting a "list index out of range" error when executing the code.

I've been searching and trying to solve the issue for hours, I think I'm not doing it right but I can't figure out the right way to do it.

```
level = [
#                     1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
# 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2
[ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],#0
[ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],#1
[ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],#2
[ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],#3
[ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],#4
[ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],#5
[ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],#6
[ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],#7
[ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],#8
]
for i in range(9):
    for j in range(23):
        if level[i][j] == 1:
            #   LEFT                 TOP                   RIGHT                 BOTTOM
        if level[i][j-1] == 1 and level[i-1][j] == 1 and level[i][j+1] == 1 and level[i+1][j] == 1:
            block = Block( j*48, i*48, 48, 48, grey, "constructor_.png")

        if level[i][j-1] == 1 and level[i][j+1] != 1 and level[i+1][j] == 1 and level[i-1][j] != 1:
            block = Block( j*48, i*48, 48, 48, grey, "constructor_t.png")

        if level[i][j-1] == 1 and level[i-1][j] == 1 and level[i][j+1] == 1 and level[i+1][j] != 1:
            block = Block( j*48, i*48, 48, 48, grey, "constructor_b.png")

        if level[i][j-1] != 1 and level[i-1][j] == 1 and level[i][j+1] == 1 and level[i+1][j] == 1:
            block = Block( j*48, i*48, 48, 48, grey, "constructor_l.png")

        if level[i][j-1] == 1 and level[i-1][j] == 1 and level[i][j+1] != 1 and level[i+1][j] == 1:
            block = Block( j*48, i*48, 48, 48, grey, "constructor_r.png")

        if level[i][j-1] != 1 and level[i-1][j] != 1 and level[i][j+1] == 1 and level[i+1][j] == 1:
            block = Block( j*48, i*48, 48, 48, grey, "constructor_tl.png")

        if level[i][j-1] == 1 and level[i-1][j] != 1 and level[i][j+1] != 1 and level[i+1][j] == 1:
            block = Block( j*48, i*48, 48, 48, grey, "constructor_tr.png")

        if level[i][j-1] != 1 and level[i-1][j] == 1 and level[i][j+1] == 1 and level[i+1][j] != 1:
            block = Block( j*48, i*48, 48, 48, grey, "constructor_bl.png")

        if level[i][j-1] == 1 and level[i-1][j] == 1 and level[i][j+1] != 1 and level[i+1][j] != 1:
            block = Block( j*48, i*48, 48, 48, grey, "constructor_br.png")

        if level[i][j-1] != 1 and level[i-1][j] != 1 and level[i][j+1] == 1 and level[i+1][j] != 1:
            block = Block( j*48, i*48, 48, 48, grey, "constructor_tbl.png")

        if level[i][j-1] == 1 and level[i-1][j] != 1 and level[i][j+1] != 1 and level[i+1][j] != 1:
            block = Block( j*48, i*48, 48, 48, grey, "constructor_tbr.png")

        if level[i][j-1] != 1 and level[i-1][j] != 1 and level[i][j+1] != 1 and level[i+1][j] == 1:
            block = Block( j*48, i*48, 48, 48, grey, "constructor_tlr.png")

        if level[i][j-1] != 1 and level[i-1][j] == 1 and level[i][j+1] != 1 and level[i+1][j] != 1:
            block = Block( j*48, i*48, 48, 48, grey, "constructor_blr.png")

        if level[i][j-1] == 1 and level[i-1][j] != 1 and level[i][j+1] == 1 and level[i+1][j] != 1:
            block = Block( j*48, i*48, 48, 48, grey, "constructor_tb.png")

        if level[i][j-1] != 1 and level[i-1][j] == 1 and level[i][j+1] != 1 and level[i+1][j] == 1:
            block = Block( j*48, i*48, 48, 48, grey, "constructor_lr.png")

        else:
            block = Block( j*48, i*48, 48, 48, grey, "constructor_tblr.png")
        self.object_list_c.add(block)
```

I'm looking forward to your help. Thanks ^.^

Comment: Which line of code are you getting the error ?

Comment: What is `Block()`?

Comment: It's the one just above "constructor_tl.png"

Comment: `Block()` is a class, it's working good.

Comment: There's a lot of copy/pasted code. See how you can remove duplication by using functions and become more expressive.

Comment: It was (8,166), but I cut off the matrix here. I had a 1 on the bottom line, when it looked for the number below it, it crashed. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `level` matrix has 9 rows and 23 columns. When you have a conditional statement like

```
if level[i][j-1] == 1 and level[i-1][j] == 1 and level[i][j+1] == 1 and level[i+1][j] == 1:
```

in the case where `j` = 22 or `i` = 9, you attempt to access an index that does not exist with `level[i][j+1]`, recalling that list indices in Python begin at 0. It is unclear to me what your code is doing, but one evident remedy would be to reduce your `range`s such that you don't attempt to access a non-existent index on the final iterations.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I had a 1 on the bottom line further in the matrix, that was the issue.

Comment: You're welcome. I would add that the error message is _very explicit_. If you see "list index out of range error", you should really think about what indices are attempting to be accessed in your code.